# Order of operations in C. ++ vs |=, which occurs first?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I have the following code that I'm reading through:

```
if( (i%2) == 0 ){ 
    *d = ((b & 0x0F) << 4); 
}
else{
    *d++ |= (b & 0x0F); 
};
```

I'm looking specifically at the `else` statement and wondering in what order this occurs?  I don't have a regular C compiler, so I can't test this.  When we are performing `*d++ |= (b & 0x0F);`, what order does this occur in?

Comment: Ouch, I'm surprised or maybe not that whomever first wrote that didn't indicate why they wrote it that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ++ is applied on the pointer `d`, not on the lvalue that is being assigned to, `*d`.

If you really want to, you can think of it like this:

1. The value of `b` is bitwise-AND:ed with the constant `0x0f`
2. The resulting bit pattern is bitwise-OR:ed into the value that `d` points at.
3. The pointer `d` is incremented to point at the next value.

Comment: So moving to the next location from the pointer happens AFTER all of the operations are applied to the original location.  Great, thanks.

Comment: Not necessarily; the semantics of the postfix operator `++` are that the side effect is applied sometime before the next sequence point, but exactly when that happens is not specified.  The compiler may store the result of `*d` into a temporary and immediately increment `d` before doing anything else.

Comment: @John: Exactly, that's why I wrote "if you really want to".

Answer (score 5):

d++ returns the value d had before it was incremented. This is then dereferenced by the *, and that location is what the |= is performed on. So the data at the location prior to incrementing d will have (b & 0x0F) ored into it.

In general, if the order of operations in a line of code is not clear at a glance, refactor the line into its constituent operations until it is. Generated code does not become any faster or more compact simply from squeezing lots of operations onto one line of C! There is no good reason to sacrifice comprehensibility in this way. Replace the line with

```
*d |= (b & 0x0F); 
d++;
```

Comment: Agreed.  Unfortunately, this is only a really small portion of a ~10,000 line script that all looks very similar..

Answer (score 2):

First the right part of `|=` is executed, then the `*d |=` assignment is done, then `d` is incremented. Usually when you have code that causes questions like that you should just rewrite it for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

`++` will occur before `|=`. Assignment operators are at the bottom of the precedence chart.

Answer (score 0):

`++` is done first. However post-increment (i.e. `d++` here) is equivalent to this `(temp=d, d++, temp)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence

it will evaluate (b & 0x0F) then apply the |= to it and assign it to *b, finally increment the value that *b in pointing to.

Comment: `|=` has nearly the lowest precedence, how do you figure it will be evaluated before the increment operator, which has nearly the highest precedence?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `*d++ |= (b & 0x0F)` breaks down as follows:

1. The expressions `*d++` and `b & 0x0F` are each evaluated once (the order in which they are evaluated is not specified; the compiler is free to evaluate `b & 0x0F` before `*d++` since the result does not depend on the order in which evaluation occurs);
2. The result of `(b & 0x0F)` is bitwise-or'd with the result of `*d++`;
3. The result of the bitwise-or operation is stored to the location originally pointed to by d;
4. At some point in all of this, the value of `d` is updated.

The expression `*d++` is parsed as `*(d++)`; i.e. you are dereferencing the result of the expression `d++`.  The expression `d++` evaluates to the current value of `d`, and at some *unspecified* point before the next sequence point (in this case, the end of the statement), the value of `d` is updated.  The side effect of updating `d` does not have to be applied immediately; it can occur before or after the assignment.